# Null Notifications When Connecting To a Web Service

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an issue with notifications appearing as a null value when attempting to connect to a web service (an XML file hosted online). The result is a NullPointerException I just need a bit of help pinpointing the source of the issue. I'm familiar with the debugger and how to log and set breakpoints - I just need a hand figuring out exactly where I should set them other than the places I already have them (I still can't find the source of the issue).

P.S.

I've included some commented out code (I apologize - I could have taken it out to shorten things up a bit - but I thought I might include it since perhaps that is where the issue lies).

Thanks in advance!

LOGCAT:

```
08-16 10:21:19.531: I/System.out(1293): Sim State5
08-16 10:21:19.591: D/Network Availability(1293): CONNECTED
08-16 10:21:19.591: D/Network Availability(1293): NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
08-16 10:21:19.751: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1293): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
08-16 10:21:39.861: D/MDN(1293): 310410
08-16 10:21:39.861: D/mdn1(1293): 676
08-16 10:21:39.861: D/mdn2(1293): 251
08-16 10:21:39.861: D/ICCID(1293): 89014103234448884342
08-16 10:21:39.861: I/System.out(1293): ICCID%1234 = 1120
08-16 10:21:39.861: I/System.out(1293): ICCID/1234 = 72134605538451283
08-16 10:21:39.901: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1293): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
08-16 10:21:45.201: V/In the parser(1293): now
08-16 10:21:45.221: V/value(1293): default,mms,supl
08-16 10:21:45.221: I/System.out(1293): size 1
08-16 10:21:45.231: I/System.out(1293): net10
08-16 10:21:45.231: I/System.out(1293): tfdata
08-16 10:21:45.371: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1293): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
08-16 10:21:53.481: I/System.out(1293): count...1
08-16 10:21:53.481: I/System.out(1293): the values in notificationActivity :port=80 mmsproxy=mms3.tracfone.com numeric=310410 mcc=310 proxy=mms3.tracfone.com name=net10 mnc=410 apn=tfdata mmsc=http://mms-tf.net mmsport=80at is   0
08-16 10:21:53.481: W/NotificationActivity(1293): Extras null
08-16 10:21:54.231: D/FIELD(1293): Name
08-16 10:21:54.231: W/dalvikvm(1293): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab31f8)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.showNotification(ConfigFinalActivity.java:431)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onClick(ConfigFinalActivity.java:208)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14111)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-16 10:21:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Nullpointer occurs on the line:

```
String value = Values.get("name").toString();
```

SOURCE:

```
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private Button mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    int i, g = 0, result = 0;
    String Result = "";
    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;

    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static String Base_URL = "https://www.mysettings.com/";
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public static String status;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        update = new UpdateActivity();
        nameArr = update.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = update.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = update.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        count = update.getCount();



        if (ApnArr.isEmpty() || mmscArr.isEmpty() || mmsportArr.isEmpty()
                || mmsproxyArr.isEmpty() || proxyArr.isEmpty()
                || portArr.isEmpty()) {
            tryagain();
        } else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            // Update APN table
            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (result != -1) {
                status = "success";

            } else {
                status = "failure";
            }

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                tryagain();
                // showAlert(getString(R.string.unchanged_net10_dialog));
            }

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            // Reduce number of steps to 6
            TotalSteps = 6;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
    //      String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.instructions_1);
    //      CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
           // TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
    //      assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.assist_update_btn:

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;

            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                //styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                //assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                //mReadAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                // mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS
                // and
                // up is selected
                // Create ConfigActivity Intent
                 Intent i = new Intent(this,
                 NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
                // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
                 startActivity(i);
            //   finish();

                // startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            }
        }  if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {

            // mAssistUpdateButton = (Button)
            // findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            // mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));

            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();// } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {




            // go back to set of instructions if read again is selected
        //  mInstructionNumber = 2;

    //      setContentView(R.layout.screen5);
////            String one_text = String
////                    .format(getString(R.string.one), TotalSteps);
////            CharSequence styledText_one = Html.fromHtml(one_text);
//          TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_one);
//          one.setTextSize(18);
//          one.setText(styledText_one);
//          String two_text = String
//                  .format(getString(R.string.two), TotalSteps);
//          CharSequence styledText_two = Html.fromHtml(two_text);
//          TextView two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_two);
//          two.setTextSize(18);
//          two.setText(styledText_two);
//          String three_text = String.format(getString(R.string.three),
//                  TotalSteps);
//          CharSequence styledText_three = Html.fromHtml(three_text);
//          TextView three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_three);
//          three.setTextSize(18);
//          three.setText(styledText_three);
    //      mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
        //  mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }



    /*
     * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
     * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
     * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
     */
    public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

        int id = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            // values2 = values1;
            values2 = getValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
                // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
                if (newRow != null) {
                    c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                    // TF Settings have been inserted
                    // Obtain the apn id
                    int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    id = c.getShort(idindex);

                    Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                            + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
        }
        return id;

    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Log.d("name", (nameArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("apn", (ApnArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("mmsc", (mmscArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("mmsproxy", (mmsproxyArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("mmsport", (mmsportArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("proxy", (proxyArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("port", (portArr.get(i)));
        Log.d("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));
        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        values.put("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));




        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }
        return values;
    }

    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Copy all data associated with the 1st record Cursor c. Return a
     * ContentValues that contains all record data.
     */
    private ContentValues copyRecordFields(Cursor c) {
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        int row_cnt = c.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Total # of records: " + row_cnt);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
            Log.d(TAG, getAllColumnNames(columnNames));
            String row = "";
            for (String columnIndex : columnNames) {
                int i = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);
                row += c.getString(i) + ":\t";
                // if (i>0)//Avoid copying the id field
                // id to be auto-generated upon record insertion
                values.put(columnIndex, c.getString(i));
            }
            row += "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, row);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Of Records");
        }
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
        private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setTitle(title)
                    .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                                    try {
                                        showNotification();
                                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            mErrorAlert = builder.create();
            mErrorAlert.show();
        }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);
        Log.d("FIELD", field);
        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        Log.d("VALUES", value);
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + TotalSteps + " (Update " + field + ":)";
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private int updateTable() throws IOException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        int insertResult = -1;
        // returned value if table is not properly updated

        try {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null,
                    "current=?", new String[] { "1" }, null);
            values = copyRecordFields(c);
            // Copy the NET10 settings into values

            // Replace T-Mo/ATT Data settings if there is no SIM or
            // NET10/T-Mo/ATT SIM is
            // present
            if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {

                // delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_tmo) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

    //      } else
                // non NET10/ non T-Mo SIM/non ATT SIM
        //      showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_net10_dialog));
            }   } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //  showErrorAlert(R.layout.assisted_settings,
        //          getString(R.string.assited_title));
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertResult;
    }

    private void completeUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.completion);
    //  TextView mCompleted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text1);
    //  String mDoneText = String.format(getString(R.string.done_text1));
    //  CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(mDoneText);

    //  mCompleted.setText(styledText);
        mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
        mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void tryagain() {
        // Displaying final layout after failure of pre-ICS automatic settings
        // update
        //setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
        String tryAgainText = "";
        CharSequence styledTryAgainText;
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text1),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
//      tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text2),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
//      tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text3),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
//      tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

    }

    // This function return a cursor to the table holding the
    // the APN configurations (Carrier table)
    public Cursor getConfigTableCursor() {
        return getContentResolver()
                .query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {

        return nameArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getApnArr() {

        return ApnArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMMSCArr() {

        return mmscArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmscProxyArr() {

        return mmsproxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmsPortArr() {

        return mmsportArr;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProxyArr() {

        return proxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPortArr() {

        return portArr;

    }

}
```

Comment: If a null pointer occurs on that line it either means `Values` is null or `Values.get("name")` is returning null, more than likely the latter. So ensure whatever is filling `Values` is being called.

Comment: It looks like you're never filling Values in the first place, so it will return null on get("name").

Comment: Hmmm... I'm thinking the issue may lie with where I call the web service but I'm not sure. If I post the portion of the source code where it calls the web service and saves the values - would that be a bit more helpful? (I really need to get this problem nailed down ASAP - I truly appreciate your help!)

Answer (score 0):

You're never filling your public static field Values in the first place, so Values.get("name") will return null, and thus toString() is called on a null variable. You attempt to create different variables named Values (or values) in your code, but you never assign anything (other than an empty new object) to the Values field, nor do you directly call any setter methods on the Values field.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! My question is why isn't the following filling the values (as I intended?)  values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
  values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
  values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
  values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
  values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
  values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
  values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
  values.put("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));

Comment: PS - If you can see an easy way to correct this - I'd love to know! (I'm converting a previously made baseline into another project so I apologize if things are a bit hairy)

Comment: You are filling a local variable values, but you are never doing anything with that local variable to assign it to the public static field Values. You may simply want to say: "Values = values;" at the end of that code, but I'm not sure because it depends on your desired application logic (which I won't have time to fully internalize).

Comment: From your code and question it looks like you may need to read up on Java scopes for methods, object fields, and static/class fields. See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/static.html

Comment: I'm adding the values where I query the web service here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lzPQ5NkWBRWe0p8PTSmEAqtZRzJkc0qNWI6O7-c3pOQ/edit?usp=sharing

(it simply was too big to fit inside the post so I had to post it on google docs)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can answer that without a lot more context, which SO isn't really the right mechanism for.